# Post formats "audio" and "video" only showing in index.php

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have files in my theme called `single-audio.php` and `single video.php`, but when I click on an audio post-format or video post-format wordpress uses the `index.php` instead of my `single-audio.php` or `single-video.php` files. Any ideas?

Comment: if those are template files, you would need to associate them to a page.  A page uses index.php as the default template file.

Comment: thanks how do I associate them?

Comment: `single-audio.php` would be a single post in a post type called `audio`, not a post format.

Comment: and a page uses page.php as the default template file, index.php is a fallback.

Comment: I understand. I'm using wordpress 3's default post-types e.g audio video, quote, gallery. My blog page shows all these format correctly. I also have a page called video with a query looping though just video posts. When I click on the permalink for a video post it is diplayed on the blog page and Id like it to show on a page-video.php

Comment: @Jared you should post that as an **answer** (ideally, along with an example `get_template_part()` call for including post format-specific content).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a huge difference between [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) and [Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). I am assuming you are using post formats, which do not have a default template file for you to use.

What you can do though is use [`has_post_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_format) to see if the post has the format you are using, and if it does, use [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to get a specific template file that you created to display there.

For example:

```
// If this post has a post format of 'video'
if( has_post_format( 'video', $post->ID ) ) {

    // Then get and display 'single-video.php'
    get_template_part( 'single', 'video' );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use single files for each post-format type you could try something like this: (paste to functions.php)

```
function post_format_template() {
global $post;
$format = get_post_format($post->ID);
if ( is_single() && $format ) {
        include('single-format-'.$format.'.php');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_format_template',10);
```

It's a possible solution, but I wouldn't recommend it, as long as you're not 100% sure about what you're doing resp. what is happening here.

Jared response is the recommended way of dealing with post-formats.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need to do the following:

1. Add a new page via the Dashboard
2. Give that new page a name like "Audio post format" and associate that page to a template. There is a selectbox which would allow you to select a template.

HTH

Comment: Thanks. According to the wordpress Template Hierarchy when displaying a post it should look for single-$posttype.php then single.php then index.php I can't undersatnd if I have a single-audio.php file why its not using that?

Comment: because you're using post-formats, not post-types. post formats don't have a dedicated template file.